# WinRT/C++ Run long for loops without causing UI freeze

Tags: c++-winrt

Is there a specific way to run long for loops without causing UI freezes on desktop applications using WinRT/C++ libraries?

The goal is that users can still switch pages without having to wait for the previous page using a long for loop to finish loading.

Comment: You usually run such computations on a secondary thread.

Comment: @Raildex Is there an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`winrt::resume_background`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#offloading-work-onto-the-windows-thread-pool) to offload the code following into the Windows threadpool, e.g.

```cpp
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ExampleAsync()
{
    winrt::apartment_context uiThread;

    // run the following code in a Windows threadpool thread.
    co_await winrt::resume_background();

    // long-running code here
    for (...)
    {
        ...
    }

    // if you want to switch to the UI thread again:
    co_await uiThread;

    // do things on the UI thread
    ...
}
```

Comment: that looks like abusing C++ syntax for me. Is that real winrt code?

Comment: That's a good starting point. Two points are probably worth noting, though: `1` A long-running task should support cancellation. That's possible, but I'm a bit rusty on the details. `2` The function should take a weak reference on the UI so as to not introduce any cycles that would prevent the UI from getting destroyed. @rai Yes, that's C++ code. I'm not sure where you spotted any sort of abuse. Sure, C++/WinRT is a stellar example of a C++ library, code you rarely see in the wild. It takes getting used to, I suppose.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for your comment! For no. 2, do you mean using `this->get_weak();` to retrieve the weak reference?

Comment: Yes. More details can be found at [strong and weak references in C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/weak-references). You might even be able to use that as a cancellation source in disguise, by attempting to upgrade it to a strong reference inside the loop, and terminating the loop when the upgrade fails (meaning that the underlying object is gone).

Comment: Is it safe to use `apartment_context` if this function is called after another `IAsyncAction` function which also uses `resume_background`, and both functions are called in the same `fire_and_forget` function?

Comment: @DonnyAndrian as far as I understand [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#programming-with-thread-affinity-in-mind), `winrt::apartment_context` captures *the calling thread*, i.e. if your method is not called from the UI thread, it will not capture the UI thread. You would be better off using `winrt::resume_foreground` and passing a dispatcher object to it. The link shows an example of that too.

Comment: Ok. Thanks guys